# UIB Datepicker Button Height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using uib-datepicker with following html:

```
<div id="date-group" class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="dateInput" type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" ng-model="searchForm.date"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And It looks like this. I am using bootstrap 3.3.6. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the CSS on the `button .btn-default` attribute. Add some padding to the button and change the vertical-align or margin. Change the positioning nonetheless.

I tried to add padding and adjust the margin of the button and the vertical-align, but the default Bootstrap styling overrides what I tried, I can't get too deep into coding right now.

[Here's a nice little tutorial on styling Bootstrap buttons](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-button-styles/) or [use the Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) to change the class of the button you're using.

Or take a look at the Angular directive for Bootstrap, [the Datepicker Popup](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup). I think that is your best bet.

Comment: Yes I can try to make it work but the problem is that "why is this happening at all?". There are several examples on the web that work without any additional effort. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/4ht8y4nw/

Comment: If I recall correct, the default styling for the button has no default padding and having a margin by default would likely conflict when combining it with other elements.